# How to add values rowwise in a grouped column

Tags: r, data.table, rowwise

I have some sensor data with 100 data entries per second. In the last column are milliseconds, which for now are all 10. How can I rowwise sum the milliseconds together, grouped by time and date.

```
testdata <- structure(list(local_date = c("26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017",  "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017",  "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017",  "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017",  "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017",  "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017",  "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017",  "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017",  "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017",  "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017",  "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017",  "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017",  "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017",  "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017",  "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017",  "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017",  "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017",  "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017",  "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017",  "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017",  "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017",  "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017",  "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017",  "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017",  "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017",  "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017",  "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017",  "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017",  "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017",  "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017",  "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017",  "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017",  "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017",  "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017",  "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017",  "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017",  "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017",  "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017",  "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017",  "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017",  "26-06-2017", "26-06-2017"), 
                           local_time = c("13:58:23", "13:58:23",  "13:58:23", "13:58:23", "13:58:23", "13:58:23", "13:58:23", "13:58:23",  "13:58:23", "13:58:23", "13:58:23", "13:58:23", "13:58:23", "13:58:23",  "13:58:23", "13:58:23", "13:58:23", "13:58:23", "13:58:23", "13:58:23",  "13:58:23", "13:58:23", "13:58:23", "13:58:23", "13:58:23", "13:58:23",  "13:58:23", "13:58:23", "13:58:23", "13:58:23", "13:58:23", "13:58:23",  "13:58:23", "13:58:23", "13:58:23", "13:58:23", "13:58:23", "13:58:23",  "13:58:23", "13:58:23", "13:58:23", "13:58:23", "13:58:23", "13:58:23",  "13:58:23", "13:58:23", "13:58:23", "13:58:23", "13:58:23", "13:58:23",  "13:58:23", "13:58:23", "13:58:23", "13:58:23", "13:58:23", "13:58:23",  "13:58:23", "13:58:23", "13:58:23", "13:58:23", "13:58:23", "13:58:23",  "13:58:23", "13:58:23", "13:58:23", "13:58:23", "13:58:23", "13:58:23",  "13:58:23", "13:58:23", "13:58:23", "13:58:23", "13:58:23", "13:58:23",  "13:58:23", "13:58:23", "13:58:23", "13:58:23", "13:58:23", "13:58:23",  "13:58:23", "13:58:23", "13:58:23", "13:58:23", "13:58:23", "13:58:23",  "13:58:23", "13:58:23", "13:58:23", "13:58:23", "13:58:23", "13:58:23",  "13:58:23", "13:58:23", "13:58:23", "13:58:23", "13:58:23", "13:58:23",  "13:58:23", "13:58:23", "13:58:24", "13:58:24", "13:58:24", "13:58:24",  "13:58:24", "13:58:24", "13:58:24", "13:58:24", "13:58:24", "13:58:24",  "13:58:24", "13:58:24", "13:58:24", "13:58:24", "13:58:24", "13:58:24",  "13:58:24", "13:58:24", "13:58:24", "13:58:24", "13:58:24", "13:58:24",  "13:58:24", "13:58:24", "13:58:24", "13:58:24", "13:58:24", "13:58:24",  "13:58:24", "13:58:24", "13:58:24", "13:58:24", "13:58:24", "13:58:24",  "13:58:24", "13:58:24", "13:58:24", "13:58:24", "13:58:24", "13:58:24",  "13:58:24", "13:58:24", "13:58:24", "13:58:24", "13:58:24", "13:58:24",  "13:58:24", "13:58:24", "13:58:24", "13:58:24", "13:58:24", "13:58:24",  "13:58:24", "13:58:24", "13:58:24", "13:58:24", "13:58:24", "13:58:24",  "13:58:24", "13:58:24", "13:58:24", "13:58:24", "13:58:24", "13:58:24",  "13:58:24", "13:58:24", "13:58:24", "13:58:24", "13:58:24", "13:58:24",  "13:58:24", "13:58:24", "13:58:24", "13:58:24", "13:58:24", "13:58:24",  "13:58:24", "13:58:24", "13:58:24", "13:58:24", "13:58:24", "13:58:24",  "13:58:24", "13:58:24", "13:58:24", "13:58:24", "13:58:24", "13:58:24",  "13:58:24", "13:58:24", "13:58:24", "13:58:24", "13:58:24", "13:58:24",  "13:58:24", "13:58:24", "13:58:24", "13:58:24", "13:58:24", "13:58:24" ), 
                           ms = c(10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10,  10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10,  10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10,  10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10,  10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10,  10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10,  10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10,  10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10,  10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10,  10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10,  10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10,  10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10,  10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10)), 
                      .Names = c("local_date",  "local_time", "ms"), row.names = c(NA, -200L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

The first 100 rows all share the same time (13:58:23) and date (26-06-2017), but they all have 10 milliseconds. The result should only have one an entry with 10 milliseconds per seconds and the following milliseconds are added to the previous ones.

This snippet would create the result with a sequence:

```
testdata$ms = rep(seq(from = 10, to = 1000, by = 10), 2)
```

But since the original data is not that clean, I have to group the data by date and time and then add the milliseconds together in a rowwise manner.

I would prefer a `data.table` solution, but `dplyr` would also work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need a grouped [`cumsum`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/cumsum.html):

```
library(dplyr) 

testdata$ms2 = rep(seq(from = 10, to = 1000, by = 10), 2)

testdata %>%
    group_by(local_date, local_time) %>%
    mutate(cumsum_ms = cumsum(ms))

   local_date local_time    ms   ms2 cumsum_ms
   <chr>      <chr>      <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
 1 26-06-2017 13:58:23      10    10        10
 2 26-06-2017 13:58:23      10    20        20
 3 26-06-2017 13:58:23      10    30        30
 4 26-06-2017 13:58:23      10    40        40
 5 26-06-2017 13:58:23      10    50        50
```

Answer (score 1):

And to add a `data.table` version:

```
testdata[, ms := cumsum(ms), by = .(local_time, local_date)]
```